# Does it make sense to encapsulate fields in a public class in a Web Service?

Tags: c#, web-services, oop, wsdl

If i have a public class in a WSDL specification that the user have to fill to send it to the server, Does it make sense to encapsulate its fields or it's better make it public too?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost never a good idea to publicly expose class fields.

Encapsulate your fields and expose them via public properties. You might be using it just like a public field for now, but you may want to add additional logic to have more control over how the field will be read or written to in the future, which will be a lot easier with properties and doesn't require any changes to the consumer code.

You can use auto-implemented properties which can be defined cleanly in one line just like a public field:

```
public string Field1 { get; set;}
```

Comment: Ok, depite in C# 3.5 this notation it's not valid i will encapsulate all of them, 'Just in case'... Thanks!

Comment: @angeek86, you're welcome. BTW, auto-implemented properties were introduced in C# 3.0 so you can use it in C# 3.5